# Displaying records in random order

Tags: php, html, sql

i am trying to figure out a way to select all the records in a table and display them in a random order.

I have heard a lot about `RAND()` like in this query

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()");
```

But to my knowledge this just selects a random number of records like 20.

How would select all the records but just display them in a random order?

Thanks

Comment: Above query returns random record....Then, what do you want?

Comment: I forgot i had the limit 1 in sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off selecting all the entries and leaving the random display to php. The whole `ORDER BY RAND()` requires *a lot* of resources. The `ORDER BY RAND()` operation actually re-queries each row of your table, assigns a random number ID and then delivers the results.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

> But to my knowledge this just selects a random number of records like 20.

*Wrong*: This will select all records then rearrange them "randomly" and give you the first row: `LIMIT 1`, just leave it out.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not much clear about your question though, you can get all records in random order by simply having following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()
```

Above query generates a random value for each row of the table, sorting that table according to these random values, and return according to the sorted row. Hence, you'll have all records with random order.

Answer (score 0):

That's just this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()
```

By dropping the `LIMIT 1` you can get all records sorted randomly ...

Answer (score 0):

Put your results in an array, then just [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) it.

And get rid of `mysql_*` functions, girls don't like them anymore.

Comment: ok, what do you mean by getting rid of mysql_*? What does it mean and what should i do instead? Thanks for the help

Comment: @moonwave99 When MySQL can output via RAND(), why would we put all on an array and shuffle it? Why doing extra coding and adding extra processing to the server?

Comment: @Arken php is telling that their database libraries like php_mysql.dll, php_mssql.dll are old and they will not be supported in the future, they want we to use mysqli or PDO based libraries ...

Comment: @Night2 not that much extra processing, if MySQL caches the raw `SELECT * FROM table` query without shuffling every time. Anyway I'm much more sold on PHP than in MySQL, so I proposed the quickest solution that came to my mind.

Comment: If someone wants all the records, then using RAND in mysql is more fast (I have tested it with a medium table around 100K records before), but if someone is needing just a couple of records, then php shuffle is more fast. Anyway even if the differences are in milliseconds, it's always better to choose the optimized one. There are even more optimized ways if you want to get a large number of random records from a large table by getting some random PKs using php and then just selecting them.